# Python3 root sudo venv

Tags: linux, virtualenv, root, sudo, python-3.5

I am running Python3.5 on Ubuntu via SSH and I have some errors there. I don't get why. If I run the following commands I get the respective errors:

```
(venv) root@servername: python3 __init__.py
```

> File "`__init__.py`", **line 1**, in <module> import flask
>   
> ImportError: No module named 'flask'

If I run it with **sudo** like this, I get another Error:

```
(venv) root@servername: sudo python3 __init__.py
```

> File "`__init__.py`", **line 2**, in <module> from .content_management import Content
>   SystemError: Parent module '' not loaded, cannot perform relative import

AND if I run it with Firefox, cause its a Flask App, the website works and shows NO ERRORS! Whats going on here??? I am going crazy with this!!

Answer (score 0):

Seems that you didn't install Flask module on the machine where you run your python script. That produces the `ImportError` you get.

Install the Flask module e.g. using `pip`:

```
$ pip install Flask
```

After you've done so, Python should be able to load the module.

Comment: I am running as root all the time like this `root@servername:/#` and if I install it with `pip3 install Flask` the first error vanishes if I run afterwards the script like this `root@servername:/# python3 __init__.py`. But if I run it with **sudo** `root@servername:/# sudo python3 __init__.py` the error is still there. And also vice versa, if I install with **sudo**, the error is away if I run it with sudo, but its still there if I run it without. Why is there a difference if I install with sudo or without especially when I am logged in as root all the time

Comment: Why do you use 'sudo' command if you are already logged in as **root** ?  'sudo' command allows users to run programs with the security privileges of superuser, so in your case (since you are already a superuser) it does not make sense.

Comment: Why do you use `sudo` command if you are already logged in as **root** ? `sudo` command allows users to run programs with the security privileges of superuser, so in your case (since you are already a superuser) it does not make sense. @saitam

Comment: Does Linux use different installation paths when I am logged in as root and use sudo additionally?

Comment: No, that's not the case. I am not completely sure, but my guess is: if you install a software using `sudo` already being **root**, you make a further restriction of who is allowed to run it. It is the same installation path in both cases, but permissions become different. Anyway, do **not** use `sudo` if already logged in as **root**. @saitam